# Calling Access sub from Outlook - Method Run of Object _Application failed

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, office-automation

I'm trying to run a subroutine in MS Access when an email is received in Outlook.

I'm using an Access.Application object and its Run method.

I get the following error: Method Run of Object _Application failed.

```
Private Sub Application_newmail()
    MsgBox "New mail"
    Dim accessdb As Access.Application
    Set accessdb = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    accessdb.opencurrentdatabase "C:/Camps.accdb", False

    accessdb.Run "test"

    accessdb.CloseCurrentDatabase

    Set accessdb = Nothing

End Sub
```

The "test" subroutine is an empty sub (after I tried and failed to call an actual sub) in the Checkdb module.

I am running Office 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code using VBScript instead of Outlook. Your code worked fine for me, except I did change your forward slash to a backslash in your database path: "C:\Camps.accdb"

Make sure you have your "Test" function/sub marked as Public.

```
Public Function Test()
    MsgBox "Test Works"
End Function
```

Comment: That's incredible! I can't believe that such a silly thing was the problem, but it was. I changed my forward slashes to backslashes in the path and now it runs beautifully. Thanks a lot!